# Get Managed Identity ObjectID of Logic App using Azure CLI/Powershell

Tags: azure, powershell

I have a logic App with Managed Identity enabled. For automation purposes, I need to use either Azure CLI or Powershell to grab the objectID of the Logic App Managed Identity to grant it access to a keyvault. 
I have done the same for Azure Data Factory using a Poweshell command like this:

```
 (Get-AzureRMDataFactoryV2 -ResourceGroupName $ResourceGroup -Name $DataFactoryName).Identity
```

Tried something similar for logic app but it does not return the identity.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Looks like the Workflow object returned by [`Get-AzLogicApp`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/az.logicapp/get-azlogicapp) doesn't have the identity property defined.

A workaround would be to use the `Get-AzResource` cmdlet instead.

```
$ID = (Get-AzResource -Name myLogicApp -ResourceType Microsoft.Logic/workflows).Identity.PrincipalId
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

Based on the previous answer by Joey Cai, you can do the following in AZ CLI also:

```
$ID = az resource show --name "myLogicApp" --resource-group "myResourceGroup" --resource-type "Microsoft.Logic/workflows" --query "identity.principalId" | ConvertFrom-Json
```